# I have to extract the year from " from_date to "to_date". How do I do that?

Tags: mysql, yearmonth

```
SELECT dm.*, e.first_name,e.last_name, e.hire_date, dm.from_date 
FROM t_dept_manager dm 
join t_employees e on dm.emp_no = e.emp_no
```

I want to find all the managers working in different departments in the year 1996. For this, I have to extract the year from `from_date` to `to_date`.

How do I do that? There is picture of my output.

emp_no, dept_no, from_date, to_date, first_name, last_name, hire_date, from_date

[image]

Comment: [YEAR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)

Comment: @ErgestBasha kindly check my question and did you notice my table query output?

Comment: I do not understand the question, please read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) and update the question

Comment: @ErgestBasha I have attached query output link. I am unable to upload the output picture

Comment: `WHERE 1996 BETWEEN YEAR(from_date) and YEAR(to_date)` should do the job.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? If you need help, please share the table structure in text form

Comment: @NicoHaase I have uploaded the output of my query here. Kindly check. I want to find all the managers working in the year 1996. For this, I have to extract the year from from_date to to_date. The above 144 records are from manager table.

Comment: As requested: please share the table structure and all other details **in text form**